# Tag for questions regarding Mathematica's design

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

I think that questions of this genre should have their own tag.  What should it be?

Example:

[DiracDelta attributes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2133/121)

Comment: Do you think questions about mma's design are ok anyway? It seems to me that there wouldn't have a specific answer and that they would lead to opiniated discussions. According to the FAQ that's not the type of questions that should be asked here.

Comment: @Sjoerd I would like to see that kind of question allowed here, but that is *my* opinion and preference.  I advocate some leeway for such questions that are honest and not prima facie griping.

Comment: What else would go under this tag? Like: [Why is Undo so limited?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1917/why-is-undo-so-limited) or "Why certain option names are strings"? Could you give more examples or provide some context please?

Comment: @István I'll use my own questions as examples: [(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8522876/618728) [(2)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8484299/618728) [(3)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8243627/618728) [(4)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5577959/618728)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this may make sense to do, since it is good to realize where in the language design which design choices were made and what are the consequences. Ultimately this would lead to a better understanding of the language. For any specific question, we only see some particular consequences of this or that design choice, but having those choices discussed more generally may provide a good way to generalize our specific experiences. This may also allow us to avoid some information duplication in our future answers, since we could refer to these "meta"-discussions. Some examples of design choices:

- Lists are implemented as arrays - this choice has a major impact on the entire language
- Alternative patterns are disallowed in the top-level definitions, so I can not e.g. define `_f | _g := 1` (it is an interesting tidbit that one *can* define `_f:=1`, but that's besides the point here).
- `Upvalues` search is limited to one level in depth
- Evaluator uses infinite evaluation model (an alternative could be a one-step evaluation, like e.g. in LISP).
- Default values for patterns are computed at definition-time
- Pure functions (in the form `Function[vars,body]`) are expressions available for destructuring, rather than black boxes
- On the other hand, various structures that are designed for speed like `Graph` or `Image` are atoms and destructuring them is not supposed to work (although it sometimes does)
- Rule replacements don't respect inner scoping constructs
- Lexical scoping is emulated with symbol creation / renaming
- Untagged exceptions with `Throw[expr]` and `Catch[expr]` are allowed
- Etc

My point is, understanding these things or even just keeping them in mind is enhancing our command of the language and leads to a deeper understanding of the language as a whole. Most of the design choices seem well justified, some may seem not, but the point is not in critisizing the design, but in being conscious about the consequences, limitations, possibilities, and pitfalls, associated with various design choices.

As for the tag name, I would suggest something like *Language-design*, or similar.

Comment: Great examples, including one "interesting tidbit" I didn't know.  Leonid, it is my understanding that at some point this site will have a web journal.  I hope that you will consider writing about some of these topics.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks. Sure I will. At some point I wanted to have my own blog on these things, but it is too much time, so I'd rather prefer to be one of the contributors for a larger blog. It is also more natural to have such a blog here, attached to this site.

Comment: Regarding tag names I have a little trouble considering Mathematica a *language* with a formal definition, and often think of it more of a complete system.  For this reason something like "Language-design" would make me think more of syntax than the deeper issues that you list.  This may be my peculiarity however.  I don't have a better tag name in mind.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think it is still certainly a language. It is a scripting language plus a system which we script with this language. I like the ideology expressed in the "External factors" subsection of [this essay](http://paulgraham.com/popular.html). So, in those terms, Mathematica provides more than just a scripting language, but I think it is still possible and fruitful to discuss the design of Mathematica-the-language, even if it is defined by a single implementation.

Comment: Well put.  I'll take a look at the essay.  Nevertheless I think a tag "design-of-mathematica" would be more precise, albeit unwieldy.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Perhaps. I don't know. I'd be fine with either one. What is important IMO is to *have* these discussions, so I very much support your initiative.

Comment: My concern is that questions like "Why can't I do `_f | _g := 1`?" frequently don't have any constructive answer.

Comment: @Brett I think that these questions would have different formulation and intentions behind them. Sometimes we would not know why certain decisions were made, but we could discuss their consequences. The example with `_f|_g:=1` is not the best one in this respect, because this is not the first thing that people would try in the first place. But, for example, the question of "why lists are implemented as arrays in Mathematica, and what are the consequences", is quite meaningful and can be answered very informatively, and many other similar questions as well.This is a different view on the system

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I'd like to add another example in the language discussion: PostScript. Like mma, it's primary use is to control a system, 2D graphics in its case, but it can be used as a [stand-alone language](http://99-bottles-of-beer.net/language-postscript-1135.html).